# At most countably many symplectic forms in given cohomology class

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a connected closed smooth manifold. Are there at most countably many non-diffeomorphic symplectic forms in any given class in $H^2(M, \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Certainly not... Take any symplectic manifold with $\dim(H^2(M))=n>1$.  Then your equivalences are no stronger than the action  of $\mathbb R^*\cdot GL(n,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb R^n\cong  H^2(M)$. The quotient is clearly not countable.

Comment: thanks aglearner, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's true and follows from the fact a vector space with a countable dense subset can't have an uncountable number of open subsets that don't intersect pairwise. Here the vector space is the space of all $C^{\infty}$  $2$-forms in the given cohomology class and the open subsets are equivalence classes of non-diffeomorphic symplectic forms. It's easy to construct a countable subset of $2$-forms, dense in $ C^{\infty}$ topology.

Comment: Yes, I was a sloppy, I should have just said that this vector space has a countable dense subset - which is what I am using

Comment: how do you construct a countable subset?

Comment: This is same as how your construct a countable dense subset of $C^{\infty}[0,1]$ (here you can take all polynomials with rational coefficients, I guess)